# Replace all the lines between two lines using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, find

I have a Config file and I want to replace all the lines between two lines using powershell
Here is my code:

```
 $HttpPath = "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\my_domain\config\fmwconfig\components\OHS\ohs1\httpd.conf"
 $NewLine = 'Options -Indexes'
 $Pattern = '(?<=<Directory />).*?(?=</Directory>)'
(Get-Content -Path $HttpPath -Raw) | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace $Pattern,$NewLine
 } | Set-Content -Path $HttpPath
```

Here is text of config the file:

```
 <Directory />
 AllowOverride none
 Require all denied
 </Directory>
```

I want to replace two lines of "Hi" and "Hello" with one line "Options -Indexes". Result should look like:

```
<Directory />
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

This script works if the file content be like:

```
<Directory /> AllowOverride none Require all denied </Directory>
```

Then Output be like:

```
<Directory />Options -Indexes</Directory>
```

But as the content of file splits in separate lines, this does not works.

Comment: What does your existing code do?

Comment: If this is xml, it is better to treat it as such. Yet `<Directory />` is a self-closed tag and `</Directory>` is a close tag... Anyways, you might try to use `Get-Content -Raw` to get the file as a single text `[String]` rather than an array of lines (`[String[]]`).

Comment: This script suppose to remove two lines between <Directory /> and </Directory> and replace it with "Options -Indexes". But now no changes get applied with the script.

Comment: <Directory /> is a start tag, and "/" here is a directory path. </Directory> is closing-tag for it.

Comment: This script applies the change if all the content present in one line. But does not work for multiple lines as mentioned in the problem statement.

Comment: If what I suspect the .txt inputfile is in fact XML, please edit your question and put in the xml content (sanitized of course)

Comment: This is the httpd.conf file for the Oracle Http Server's Instance configuration. I have already tried with the original 'httpd.conf' file but got same results as stated in problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$Pattern = '(?s)(?<=<Directory />\r?\n).*?(?=</Directory>)'
$NewLine = "{0}{1}" -f 'Options -Indexes',[Environment]::NewLine
(Get-Content http.conf -raw) -replace $Pattern,$NewLine | Set-Content http.conf
```

**Explanation:**

Using the `-Raw` switch of `Get-Content` allows you to work with multiple lines without having to store previous line outputs. It reads the entire file as a single string instead of an array of strings.

The `s` modifier (used with syntax `(?s)`) is the single-line modifier. It allows the regex character `.` to match newline characters, which you will have since your target text is between two other lines.

The mechanism `(?<=text)` is a positive lookbehind assertion from the current position. It expects `text` to be behind the current position. `\r?\n` matches 0 or 1 carriage return and 1 newline. `text` will not be removed here.

The mechanism `(?=text)` is a positive lookahead assertion checking that `text` is ahead of the current position. `text` will not be removed here.

`-f` is the string format [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7). This is not required, but it is a useful way to construct a string with programmable parts.

Comment: Thanks. This works. But the closing-tag is coming one step above with the new line added. How to shift that closing-tag to separate line?

Comment: That must mean `[Environment]::NewLine` is not working for you. You could replace it with ```"`r`n"```.